# How to correctly use shelves when working with classes in Python?

Tags: python, persistence, pickle, shelve

I'm making some code to learn how to use classes better. I learnt about persistence in programs and about shelves in Python.
I'm trying to make my user input some stuff, which then is used to make an object of my only class.

```py
import shelve
filearch = shelve.open('archive')
filearch['patients'] = {}

class Patient():
    def __init__(self, name='', surname='', notes=''):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.notes = notes

def makeone():
    print('Insert a name')
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    print('Insert a surname')
    cognome = input('surname: ')
    print('Insert notes')
    data = input('notes: ')
    a = {'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'notes': notes}
    return a
def addone():
    users_pat = Patient(**makeone())
    return users_pat

def save(user_paz):
    return filearch['patients'].update({user_paz : a)
```

Can someone please explain me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You never call your `makeone` and `addone` functions.

Comment: Don't open a file at the beginning of your script. Do that inside the `save` function. And close the file as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: I call them all, I just posted them because are those who not work

Comment: @zvone Additionally, [using `with` for file handling](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) lets Python manage closing the file for you (this is also how [the `shelve` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) does it). [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) is very slick for handling resources that need to be opened/closed/cleaned up/etc. @Kodeeo You're not syncing or closing the shelf, and your use of `update()` might not work as expected without `writeback=True`. You may want to check the doc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to fix in this code.

Firstly, it doesn't run because this line is invalid, it's missing a closing '}'.

```
return filearch['patients'].update({user_paz : a)
```

Once that is fixed, running the code like this

```
user = addone()
save(user)
```

results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    user = addone()
  File "test.py", line 21, in addone
    users_pat = Patient(**makeone())
  File "test.py", line 18, in makeone
    a = {'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'notes': notes}
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

This is because in `makeone` you assign the input values to `nome`, `cognome` and `data` but try to save the non-existent variables `name`, `surname` and `notes`.

If we fix these names and run again we get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    save(user)
  File "test", line 26, in save
    return filearch['patients'].update({user_paz: a})
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

In `a` is the name of a variable that you create in `makeone`, but that name is only valid inside the `makeone` function.  the `save` function only knows about the `user_paz` variable that you have passed to it, so change

```
return filearch['patients'].update({user_paz : a})
```

to

```
return filearch['patients'].update({user_paz : user_paz})
```

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, you need to close the shelve file to be sure the content are saved.

Here's an improved version of your code: it saves the input and then reports on the contents of the shelve file.

```
import shelve


class Patient:
    def __init__(self, name='', surname='', notes=''):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.notes = notes

    def __repr__(self):
        # A readable representation of a Patient object.
        return '<Patient(name={0.name}, surname={0.surname}, notes={0.notes}>'.format(self)

    # Use the same readable representation if str(patient) is called.
    __str__ = __repr__


def makeone():
    print('Insert a name')
    name = input('Nome: ')
    print('Insert a surname')
    surname = input('surname: ')
    print('Insert notes')
    notes = input('notes: ')
    a = {'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'notes': notes}
    return a


def addone():
    users_pat = Patient(**makeone())
    return users_pat


def save(user_paz):
    with shelve.open('archive') as archive:
        archive['patients'] = {user_paz.name: user_paz}
    return


def report():
    with shelve.open('archive') as archive:
        for name, patient in archive.items():
            print(name, patient)
    return


def main():
    patient = addone()
    save(patient)
    report()
    return
```